# Concatenate value of two fields before publishing to kafka topic using Connect SMT

Tags: apache-kafka, transform, apache-kafka-connect

Is **ReplaceField** transform used only to replace or mask the field name Or can I change the value of the field as well using some expression , with static values ?

My need is to concatenate value of two fields before publishing to kafka topic.

Answer (score 2):

**`org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField`** is used to add static values or topic metadata (topic name, partition, timestamp, offset, etc), but not concatenate, or use expressions.

**`org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField`** is used to rename/filter existing fields, not add new ones.

---

That being said, you're going to have to create your own `Transformation` subclass that can merge a list of fields.

Or publish the existing "raw" data then use Kafka Streams or KSQL to create the "enriched" topic.